# How to build a child sponsorship website in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have been given the task of building a Drupal site for child sponsorship. The functionality needs to include sponsors registering on the site to be able to sponsor a child.

I have created a content type to display the child's information and I'm using a payment module to make payments for the child through Paypal. My problem is that there should be a relationship between the sponsor and the child he/she is sponsoring so that it is visible on their profile page.

Any idea about how to go about it would be highly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.
You question may be better over at the [Drupal Answers site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes using [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) on registration page, add field which will populate list of children, and then Sponsors can select any child while registering on site. You can use that reference field to show on Profile.

Cheers!!!